# How can you select text in a windows command prompt without using the mouse?

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know how to select a portion of text within a windows command prompt without using a mouse? e.g. shift + left/right arrow. I have tried lots of different command prompts (cmd, powershell, cygwin, mintty) and have yet to find a shell which can do this without using a mouse. I know it's possible as I do it all the time in terminal.app on mac os x.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319448/how-can-i-select-text-in-git-bash-terminal-in-windows-7-without-mouse

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Ignacio said however you need to ensure "QuickEdit Mode" is enabled from the CMD properties.

1. ALT+Space -> E -> M (now in mark mode)
2. move the pointer using arrow keys
3. Hold shift and select the area to copy
4. Hit Enter and it's now on the clipboard

Comment: Ignore me.  Don't need QuickEdit mode

Comment: This works, but is there a way to do this with the mouse?

Comment: For me its `ALT + SPACE + E + K`.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>, `Mark`, arrow keys, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, arrow keys, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: "does not work in mintty" :))

Comment: @akira: mintty probably does not use a Windows console.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams How do you make button icons?

Comment: @AndrejaKo: <kbd>Alt</kbd>

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: thats what the smiley at the end was for.

Comment: `Mark` can be selected by pressing `M`.

Answer (score 4):

Please be aware, that ALT+Space > **E** > **M** only works on **English** locales of Windows. In other language versions the letters after the ALT+Space can differ.
e.g. on a **German** version of Windows have to press ALT+SPACE > **B** > **M**

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me on Windows 10 v1909: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> or Top-left icon (or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>) > Edit (<kbd>E</kbd>) > Mark (<kbd>K</kbd>).

Then, you can select text holding Shift and pressing arrow keys.

[image: Screenshot: Icon > Edit > Mark]